# Limit dispatch_async task time in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I make some server calls using dispatch_async.
Sometimes this calls take to much time due to slow internet connection.

How can i set limit in seconds - for example: task has 3 seconds to be done otherwise it stops.

Comment: so are you basically looking for a timeout? If so, try setting a timeout in the n/w call.

Answer (score 2):

**As [MultiColour Pixel says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366127/2976878), you should really be using `NSURLSession` for this.**

However, if you're still looking for a GCD answer, here it is...

---

### You can easily use a semaphore to achieve a timeout for your request.

You just have to create a semaphore with an initial value of `0` and then use `dispatch_semaphore_wait` in order to wait for the semaphore to be signalled when the network task is completed, or for the request to time-out.

**Therefore if your network task is synchronous, you'll want to do something like this...**

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("serialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) // your GCD queue

...

dispatch_async(queue, {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0) // create semaphore

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        self.doNetworkTask()
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); // signal semaphore on completion
    })

    let timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) // 3 second time-out
    let returnValue = dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout)

    guard returnValue == 0 else { // return value is non-zero if the request timed out

        // request timed out, cancel the request here.
        self.stopNetworkTask()
        return // prevent further execution if network task was unsucessful
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // do processing after request success
    })

})
```

**Or if your network task is asynchronous...**

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("serialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) // your GCD queue

...

dispatch_async(queue, {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0) // create semaphore

    self.doNetworkTaskWithCompletion({
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); // signal semaphore on completion
    })

    let timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) // 3 second time-out
    let returnValue = dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout)

    guard returnValue == 0 else { // return value is non-zero if the request timed out

        // request timed out, cancel the request here.
        self.stopNetworkTask()
        return // prevent further execution if network task was unsucessful
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // do processing after request success
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're requesting data from a server, you should probably be using something like [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/). When you're setting up your session you can set the timeouts that you're wanting.